# Prove that $\frac{\sqrt{N}}{(\frac{N(N - 1)}{2} + 1)^2} \le 1$ for $N \ge 2$.

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

I am trying to prove that for natural numbers $N \ge 2$, the following expression would always be true:

$$
\frac{\sqrt{N}}{\Big(\frac{N(N - 1)}{2} + 1\Big)^2} \le 1.
$$

I can clearly see that when I calculate. For example: when $N = 2$,
$$
\frac{\sqrt{N}}{\Big(\frac{N(N - 1)}{2} + 1\Big)^2}  = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\Big(\frac{2(2 - 1)}{2} + 1\Big)^2}  = .3536.
$$
Or when $N = 10$,
$$
\frac{\sqrt{N}}{\Big(\frac{N(N - 1)}{2} + 1\Big)^2}  = \frac{\sqrt{10}}{\Big(\frac{10(10 - 1)}{2} + 1\Big)^2}  =.0015.
$$
But how do I prove it for the general case? TIA.

Comment: I've added a couple of examples now. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: No problem.  This question is spot on.  Thanks Hasan!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By AM-GM inequality,

$$\frac{1}{2} \bigg( \frac{N(N-1)}{2} + 1 \bigg) \geq \sqrt{\frac{N(N-1)}{2}}$$.

All quantities being positive, inequality is preserved when you take the square. Hence,

$$\bigg( \frac{N(N-1)}{2} + 1 \bigg)^2 \geq 2N(N-1)$$

It is now obvious that $2N(N-1) \geq \sqrt{N}$ since $N \geq 2$. Hence you have your result.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to show this. For example, for all $\ N\geq2,\ $

$$\frac{N(N - 1)}{2}\geq \frac{N}{2}>0$$

Therefore, $$ \frac{N(N - 1)}{2}+1\geq \frac{N}{2} + 1>0$$

which implies

$$ \left(\frac{N(N - 1)}{2}+1\right)^2\geq \left(\frac{N}{2} + 1\right)^2 = \frac{N^2}{4} + N + 1 > N.$$

Finally we have

$$
\frac{\sqrt{N}}{\Big(\frac{N(N - 1)}{2} + 1\Big)^2} < \frac{\sqrt{N}}{N}< 1.
$$